# Concealed door vs Secret door

Tags: osr, adnd-1e, dungeon

In AD&D 1st edition, what is the difference between a concealed door and a secret door?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are defined on p97 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide*

**Concealed doors** are doors hidden in some way:

- Behind a curtain
- Covered with plaster
- Trap door under a rug

A PC can normally find a concealed door just by checking his surroundings well.

**Secret doors** are portals that look like a normal wall to the naked eye.  Typically it takes more effort to discover a secret door.

Comment: Thanks Pat.  I stared at that page 5 times earlier today and completely missed it down at the bottom.  I knew it had to be somewhere there.

Comment: @Stewbob - no problem.  The first edition rules are jam packed with information, but finding the one particular datum you need can be a trying experience sometimes!

Comment: Trap door under a rug is so cliche' that as soon as you say there's a rug in a room, players ask to look under it. :)

Comment: @stefano true, but every so often they get lazy at the wrong time. :)

Comment: I commonly rule that a Thorough (time-consuming) Search automatically finds all Concealed doors, but Secret portals require the usual die-roll checks.

Comment: @stefano: I don't tell them there's a rug unless they ask about the floor specifically.